# Ubuntu System start-up

Tags: ubuntu-core, ubuntu-drivers

I was fixing a problem with youtube-dl 
I installed Python 2 and python 3
Then, I installed Python 3 when I opened the bin folder it was empty.

When I restarted the lab it turn the following line in a black page:
canonical livepatch is available for installation.

What should I do?
Will my files be deleted?

Comment: It's not clear what your did, or what happened. Python3 is already included with every install of Ubuntu, so "*I installed Python 3*" is confusing.

Comment: I first uninstalled python 3, even though there was a warning.